# Email throttling option in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

we  moved to Salesforce Marketing Cloud platform recently, our requirement set the maximum limit for emails per hour is to **100000** emails and no more than **1 million** emails in a day.

Is there any out of box functionality available for Scheduling within a single campaign, i.e send the total audience throughout the day (e.g. 1 million subscribers per day at max, send 100k every hour), In other words we need to restrict daily/hourly email send limits.

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved by Send Throttling.  It is not necessary to contact customer support as this can now be done within the Setup Application!  Here is the clickpath to enabling this:

Setup > Platform Tools > Email Studio > Email Optional Features > "Send Throttling"

As for the secondary part of the question, you can cap the total sends by defining a specific "send window" such as 10:00 AM to 8:00 PM which, in this case would achieve sending to no more than a million a day.   100k per hour/no more than 1 million sent.

Finally, the user in another comment in this thread notes that it isn't possible to use Salesforce Audiences, but this is untrue.   Utilizing Synchronized Data Sources will allow for you to use A/B Testing, Dynamic Content, and any other things that you might want to when testing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature called Send Throttling, which isn't activated by default. You can contact the support team, they will activate if for you.

Comment: With Send Throttling you can limit the amount sent per hour, but I don't think you can cap total sends. The sends throttle through the time period sent, but if the total list is not sent it will continue the following day through the time period.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is send throttling is not availible (even if enabled) if you are sending to SF Campaigns or Reports using the MarketingCloud/SF Connector and your emails are built using the Classic Editor.

You can throttle to you hearts delight to any audience using the new Content Builder... but then if you do that, you can't use any of the cool testing functionality (like A/B testing or dynamic content) if you're using audiences kept in SF.

The Integration of MarketingCloud and Salesforce is far from integrated.